# Alarm Repeat in Android 8

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-8.0-oreo

Can you explain me why this code work well on Android Lollipop but i don't work well on Android Oreo ? The code set an Alarm that start after 5 second and repeat every 4 second. It send a broadcast and MyReceive show a Toast. In android 8, it start in late and the next broadcast don't send every 4 second but in random time (in late). What I can do ?

```
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    private final String LOG_TEST = "LOG_TEST";
    private Button bStart, bStop;
    private Intent intent;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    public static final String MY_CUSTOM_ACTION = "mio.broadcast";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this,0,intent,0);

        bStart=(Button)findViewById(R.id.bStart);
        bStop= (Button)findViewById(R.id.bStop);


        bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Calendar attivazione = Calendar.getInstance();

                alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, attivazione.getTimeInMillis()+5000,4000,pendingIntent);
            }
        });

        bStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(alarm!=null){
                    alarm.cancel(pendingIntent);
                }
            }
        });


    }


}
```

MyReceiver

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Vibrazione inserita", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.redwi.alerttry">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I hope that you can help me thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The precision of [`setRepeating`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) is not guaranteed to be exact and could vary from device to device unpredictably. If you need more precise scheduling, use [`setExact`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) and reschedule the alarm yourself. From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)):

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS
>   will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There
>   are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery
>   guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and
>   setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose
>   targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the
>   previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when
>   requested.

Comment: Thanks for the info! 
How can reschedule the alarm 1 for day also in background?

Answer (score 0):

> Can you explain me why this code work well on Android Lollipop but i don't work well on Android Oreo ?

`AlarmManager` is not designed for doing things that frequently. Of note:

- On Android 4.4+, `setRepeating()` will be inexact, meaning that the alarm can occur anywhere within the period
- On Android 5.1+, `setRepeating()` will be limited to a minimum period of one minute
- On Android 6.0+, your alarms will be affected by Doze mode, and perhaps by app standby, causing them to run infrequently when the device is not on a charger and not moving

> What I can do ?

If you wish to show a `Toast` every few seconds from the foreground, use `postDelayed()`:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  Covered in detail in the book _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.post;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PostDelayedDemo extends Activity implements Runnable {
  private static final int PERIOD=5000;
  private View root=null;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    root=findViewById(android.R.id.content);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    run();
  }

  @Override
  public void onStop() {
    root.removeCallbacks(this);

    super.onStop();
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    Toast.makeText(PostDelayedDemo.this, "Who-hoo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
         .show();
    root.postDelayed(this, PERIOD);
  }
}
```

(from [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.11/Threads/PostDelayed))

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The idea is to schedule 2 alarm 1 time for day (at different time). The time that i set is for debug only.

Comment: @Pab: Use `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle()` on Android 6.0+, `setExact()` on Android 4.4-5.1, and `set()` on previous Android versions. Do your own repeating logic, as there is no exact-repeat option on Android 4.4+.